# Double quotes problems with Postgres

Tags: sql, django, database, postgresql

I am using Django with postgres. Here's the snippet of my code which I am using to create tables in the db.

```
class user(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    role_id = models.ForeignKey(role,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user'
```

My question is:

1. why is the user table getting renamed as "user" (with quotes)
2. why is the role_id getting named as role_id_id where as I have clearly mentioned role_id to be my column name?
   [image]

Comment: If you use a `ForeignKey`, then it will create a "twin field" named `field_id` that contains the primary key, this is why you do *not* use an `_id` suffix in a `ForeignKey` field.

Comment: The double quotes around the table names are to protect case sensitivity.  A python string is case sensitive, but without the quotes will be lowercased in postgres.  

It doesn't affect anything and you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: The double quotes are not necessary but don't hurt anything in your case.  If the table had uppercase characters, the quotes would be necessary to preserve them.  Otherwise the query parser would convert all characters to lowercase.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem. Django does not create a 'twin field', there is only one FK field per relationship. Django just appends whatever the field name in the model is with '_id' when it creates the table, unless you override with a ```db_column```.  Also that field does not contain the PK as you can have duplicate entries in a FK. Also the FK does not have to point at a PK field, just one that is ```UNIQUE```.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: no, in fact you can even assign to that field, for example `user.role_id_id=4` for example. The `ForeignKey` is not saved in the database, since well a database has not really a `ForeignKey` field, but it also creates a field with the same type that can accept values. Note that a *model* field however does not per se maps to a database field. In fact a lot of packages have fields that boil down to for example two or three fields at the database, or vice versa.

Comment: Again you are wrong. See [Tutorial Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial02/#creating-models) and the SQL the output for ```polls_choice``` table. A FK is created. In Django when you use ```role_id``` from table ```user`` you get the model instance that the role_id_id field is pointing to in the ```role``` table. When you use role_id_id you get/set the actual value of the data stored in the ```role_id_id``` field.  There is only one field involved and it is a FK. Don't believe me look at your tables and run queries to see what ```role_id``` and ```role_id_id``` return.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem. You really need to study up on FK's in databases as you have some misconceptions on how they work and how ForeignKey works with them.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: but you have Django's `ForeignKey`, which has nothing to do with the database. It makes migrations to create columns at the database side. For example the `on_delete` part is not done through a trigger in the database, it is done through a callable by Django: https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/db/models/deletion.py#L23-L29. Another example is a `ManyToManyField` which does not map to a column at all, or a field that maps to multiple columns in the database (https://gist.github.com/gipi/2401143).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: in short, Django's model fields, have not much to do with a database column. In fact for example in Djongo, they do not even map on columns in the first place.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: furthermore if you fetch `.role_id`, you don't get the the `role_id_id` field, you get the *model* object, like you say yourself. Hence that is not the field in the database. It attaches logic. It is a common mistake to map Django fields one-on-one on a database column. The `GenericForeignKey` is the same, here there is no field at all, it simply uses values of two other fields.

Comment: Django uses the value in the FK field to look up the row in the parent and fetch  a model instance using the FK value. There is a FK relationship between the child table and the parent both at the model level and at the database level(Sqlite3 excepted). Don't change the subject with GenericForeignKey.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: What I mean is that there exists an extra conceptual field at the Python/Django layer, that this does not exists at the database layer is of course quite normal. One stores the target field value, one acts as a wrapper, basically like a `GenericForeignKey` also acts as a wrapper. Evidently Django tries to enforce a foreign key constraint. But first of all, an FK constraint is not even something that strictly speaking belongs to a column, since it can span multiple columns, it is also not relevant to how Django works. It is an added level of security, but that's all.

Comment: Especially since the aim is to eventually make Django database-agnostic framework, it thus means that Django models can not interfere much on what the database is doing in the first place. Although it is bit too optimistic for conplex fields like a JSON field, etc. the aim is that if the backend changes, all the models can simply be put in another database environment.

Comment: Furthermore if one uses `role_id_id` in this case, it will not directly go to the database either. You can define models in Django, that have a different name in the database representation. For example, if you defined `role = ForeignKey(Role, db_column='role_bla')`, then still, `.role_id` would be the models "field" to directly set value of the "target field", so even if the database name is different, that does not change the model name for it.

Comment: The more you write the less sense you make. I'm ending this as you have now reached the point of contradicting  yourself:"in fact you can even assign to that field, for example user.role_id_id=4 for example." to "Furthermore if one uses role_id_id in this case, it will not directly go to the database either. "

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: no, what I mean is that the name `role_id_id` does not *per se* maps on the database name :). So there is evidently a *column* `role_id_id` here in the database, but we can change that, with `db_name`, right? But that does not mean that the *Django field* in the model now is changed. So imagine that I wrote `role_id = models.ForeignKey(Role, db_column='role_bla')`, and now the *database column* has name `role_bla`, but in Django you can still use `role_id` to assign values. This basically shows that your assumption of one-to-one mapping is incorrect.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: how is that contradicting it. You should make the clear destinction between a *model **field*** and a *database **column***. If you consider these the same, then I perfectly understand that you reach inconsistency. This is exactly what I tried to produce here: a proof of *inconsistency* of the claim that fields and columns *are* the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading few answers on Stackoverflow, I think the reason why instead of user (without quotes) a "user" table was getting created is because user is a reserved keyword in postgres and cannot be used for the table name.
Coming to the second question about the _id part:

```
Behind the scenes, Django appends "_id" to the field name to create
its database column name.
```

Comment: All that effort put into docs [FK](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) and no reads them:"Behind the scenes, Django appends "_id" to the field name to create its database column name. In the above example, the database table for the Car model will have a manufacturer_id column. (You can change this explicitly by specifying db_column) "

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your app name contains an uppercase letter, your app name must be all lowercase

Example:

app name : **M**ain_app + table name : user --> database table : **"**Main_app.user**"**

app name : main_app + table name : user --> database table : main_app.user